# Calculating the SUM of individual columns in DataBricks

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to calculate the sum of individual columns in a table. The table contains 267 columns in total and most are int, some are floats, and one is a string.
I can obviously do:

```
SELECT SUM(column1) as column1...
FROM db
```

Is there a way to display a report of only the sums of individual columns without having to write sum(ColumnName) 267 times? Using SQL

Comment: When you have `SELECT a,b,c FROM test;` you only need to replace a `,` with `),SUM(`, and then add `SUM(` for the first column, and `)` to the last. Notepad can do that (when you are running on Windows)   Most tools can generate the starting query. so I do not see a problem of 267 time doing something..... 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I can think of is you can do this with a loop in Pyspark , an example is as below -

```
df_dtypes = sparkDF.dtypes

num_col_list = [c if d not in ['string','datetime','timestamp'] for c,d in df_dtypes]

sum_list = [F.sum(F.col(x)).alias(x) for x in num_col_list]

sparkDF.select(*sum_list).show()
```